# The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client Error on App Server

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, web-applications, odp.net

I have a 64 bit Windows 8 machine where I am compiling the application with the Oracle client 12c and using Oracle Client 4.x (64 bit) .net framework 4.0

And on my application server which also 64 bit Windows server 2008, Oracle Client 11 .net framework 4.0.

If I compile the application from my PC and deploy on IIS, it constantly giving me error that

```
"The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client"
```

But if I compile the application from the inside of the Application server and then deploy it on IIS, it works fine..

**Can someone pinpoint me where I am doing wrong or what have I missed?**

Comment: Well, why don't you install the Oracle 11 client on your workstation?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, by 'workstation', you mean my Development PC? and also should I have to install both client (64 and 32 bits)?

Comment: Yes, your dev PC.  You need to install 64 bit, I assume.

Comment: I have now Oracle client 12 on dev server, 1- should I have uninstall it? 2- does client11 have oracle dev tool for VS?